# Is there a way to strongly type a property of an object typed as 'any'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a parent object that is typed as 'any' that cannot change (I am using the `this` object in a unit test), and I am defining a property of the parent object, but no matter what I do it is always loosely typed with the 'any'. Casting doesn't seem to do anything until run time either. Is there a way to strongly type my property before run time so I can get Typescript to throw an error when assigning a bogus property?

```
interface AType {
    bar: number
    bas: string
}

let something: any = {};

// Make this property respect 'AType' typing.
something.anythingElse = <AType>{
 bar: 1,
 bas: 'one',
};

// Doesn't throw an Error but it should
something.anythingElse.bogusAssignment = '1234';
```

Comment: You could do `let something: {[key: string]: AType}`. Says that `something` will be an object with string keys and AType object values

Comment: or `let something: { [key: string]: any, anythingElse?: AType } = {};`

Comment: I should have added this to the question, but  I am adding something to the `this` variable of a unit test, and cannot change the objects type from `any`.

Comment: Then use **type assertion** (https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html) for such. Define an interface with the entire desired constraints, then make a type assertion like: `(something as MyInterface).anythingElse.bonusAssignment = '1234';`.

Comment: That would be one way to do it @briosheje, yes. But I was hoping for an easier solution than changing every reference of this property to use type assertion. This may be the only way though...

Comment: @ZachShuffield if the original value is meant to be of type `any`, **your** code should work around that, since the original object is meant to be of that type specifically. Since it's just type assertion here, you may want to rather make a **method** that returns the object "casted" to the desired type so that, if someday, you need to change it, you can do that in a single entry point. Perhaps you should take a look at **user defined type guards** as well, if you're not aware of them already: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html#user-defined-type-guards

Comment: You've mentioned a few times that various solutions don't apply to your use case for various reasons.  You might consider editing this question into a [mcve] which captures these aspects of your use case, if you want to increase the chance of receiving a suggestion that might work for you.

Answer (score 1):

After the comments above, aside from the regular **type assertion**, you may think about using a **type guard** instead:

```
interface AType {
    bar: number
    bas: string
}

let something: any = {};

something.anythingElse = <AType>{
 bar: 1,
 bas: 'one',
};

// below type guard definition.
function isAType(arg: any): arg is AType {
    return arg && arg.anythingElse; // <-- add further type checkings here.
}

const somethingElse = something.anythingElse;
if (isAType(somethingElse)) {
    somethingElse.bogusAssignment = '1234';
                //^---- this will throw compile error and intellisense error as well.
}
```

Here, bogusAssignment will not work.

Working playground: [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20AType%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bas%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20something%3A%20any%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Asomething.anythingElse%20%3D%20%3CAType%3E%7B%0D%0A%20bar%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20bas%3A%20'one'%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20isAType(arg%3A%20any)%3A%20arg%20is%20AType%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20arg%20%26%26%20arg.anythingElse%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Doesn't%20throw%20an%20Error%20but%20it%20should%0D%0Aconst%20somethingElse%20%3D%20something.anythingElse%3B%0D%0Aif%20(isAType(somethingElse))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20somethingElse.bogusAssignment%20%3D%20'1234'%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

Edit: for the comments below, here is another approach you may take: [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20AType%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bas%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20something%3A%20any%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Asomething.anythingElse%20%3D%20%3CAType%3E%7B%0D%0A%20bar%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20bas%3A%20'one'%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20isAType(arg%3A%20any)%3A%20arg%20is%20AType%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20arg%20%26%26%20arg.anythingElse%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20somethingAsSomethingElse(arg%3A%20any)%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20anythingElse%3A%20AType%0D%0A%7D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20arg%20as%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20anythingElse%3A%20AType%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AsomethingAsSomethingElse(something).anythingElse.somethingWrong%3B%0D%0A)

Comment: TIL what a type guard is, thanks! Again, this solves the issue, but it doesn't seem to be a good solution for my specific issue. I would have to wrap every unit test in an if statement for this guard.
I'm really looking for a single line solution, or even if one exists

What I really want is to do something to this line so that it recognizes that something.anythingElse has the type of AType.
`something.anythingElse = <AType>{`

Comment: @ZachShuffield I don't think you can find any other solution other than type assertion. Typescript was invended exactly to avoid such situations specifically, you should redesign your code to work around the issue, it's matter of **designing** code efficiently, in that case. You may check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33615680/how-to-properly-change-a-variables-type-in-typescript. You may want to make a method whose scope is just to cast the object to an interface, so that you can do a replace in the entire code. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

What does prevent you to give a stronger type to the parent?

```
something: Partial<{anythingElse: AType}>
```

Comment: The parent in my use case is the `this` keyword in a jasmine unit test. Can't retype `this` (AFAIK...)